# Remove Zeros Before Decimal- PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, number-formatting

Numbers under 1 are currently being represented with a leading zero before the decimal point (example: 0.50). Because I'm working with baseball statistics (which almost never have the zero before the decimal) I would like to remove that. I want to keep the number before the decimal if its greater than 1 though. How would I do that?

For instance if I'm working with this measure. Is there something I can add to that?

```
AVG = SUM(Batter[H])/sum(Batter[AB])
```

Thanks. I appreciate the help.

Here is some sample data

```
Name            AB  H   
Gleyber Torres  546 152 
Brett Gardner   491 123 
Aaron Judge     378 103 
Adam Ottavino   0   0
Aroldis Chapman 0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NAN error is occurring because you are dividing by 0. You should add an IF condition to avoid that:

```
AVG = IF(sum(Batter[AB])=0,BLANK(),SUM(Batter[H])/sum(Batter[AB]))
```

To tackle the formatting issue you can use the FORMAT function as mentioned by Andrey:

```
AVG = IF(sum(Batter[AB])=0,BLANK(),FORMAT(SUM(Batter[H])/sum(Batter[AB]),"###.0#"))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or simply use [DIVIDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/divide-function-dax) and get rid of the whole IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it isn't directly possible. However, in the last step (the visualization of the data), you can convert the decimal number to text and format it as you want. For example, your measure could be like this:

```
AVG = FORMAT(SUM(Batter[H])/SUM(Batter[AB]), "#,###.00")
```

This will give you 2 decimal places (0 means that there will be a digit displayed at this position), but the digits before the decimal are optional (# means it will show a digit, but will omit the leading zeros) or here are some examples:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the help Andrey. I probably shouldve added that some rows are null as well. The null rows return `-nan(ind)`

Comment: Could you update your question with example data, because I don't think this is a direct result of the formatting.

Comment: I take that back. `-nan(ind)` is actually happening when the batter has 0 in the H and AB field. So in my sample data Ottavino and Chapman are showing `-nan(ind)`